# Initializer threw an exception

Tags: vb.net

I get an error "The type Initializer for 'Myproject' thew an exception. It's rather bizarre.

In My Main form I have the following in my Button-click event:

```
MyShip.Name = "Lolipop"
```

That one line causes the error.

MyShip is declared in a module called GlobalVariables.vb as follows:

```
Friend MyShip As New clsShip
```

clsShip has a property called Name.

I'm not sure what's happening. Oddly, I can set `MyShip.Name = "Lolipop"` in the form's LOAD() event, but can't do that in any of the button click events.

Ideas?

Comment: Tell us what the inner exception says - thats the good part

Comment: Okey, I kinda found the problem. There's a class that isn't getting instantiated. Funny thing -- Visual studio doesn't throw an error -- it just ignored it. When I tossed everything in a try/catch block, that's when I found it.

I ended up going to DEBUG-EXCEPTIONS and turned everything on. Now I can properly see the error when I run the program.